# How do I avoid a Azure write job adding blank rows?

Tags: datastage

I read a .csv file from Azure storage and write it back into Azure storage as a .csv without any changes.

Input file:

```
Name, State, Bank
Jon, TX, WFC
Bob, CA, JPC
Jim, NY, BAC
```

Output file:

```
Name  , State, Bank
Jon   , TX   , WFC

Bob   , CA   , JPC

Jim   , NY   , BAC
```

How should I avoid the blank rows added to the output file?

Answer (score 0):

Had to chose the CSV file format instead of delimited